# Is there a case where Applications need to do it's own File corruption checks with file systems like EXT4 and XFS and recent Linux OS like Red-Hat 8

Tags: linux, files, ext4, xfs, corruption

What I presumed is

- File systems like EXT4 and XFS. Writes blocks to disk (Could be a Hard Disk or a SSD) along with a checksum.
- When Reading back, if checksum fails, [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) operation will NOT return data and will indicate error or EOF (or no data).
- On a re-boot (even if it is after a abrupt shutdown where OS in-memory pages were not flushed), Linux OS checks the integrity of file blocks using checksum and if an application tries to read a file where such error detected blocks are part of it, [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) operation will fail when the read reaches the afore mentioned block.
- If the corruption detected(by Linux OS) block is in the middle of a file. Even if subsequent blocks does NOT contain an error, read operation will fail after reaching the corrupted block and application will never be able to read beyond the corrupted block.
  e.g. Let's say file size is 4KB, and block size 1KB. So this file will be spread across 4 blocks A,B,C and D. Let's say Linux detected that block C is corrupted. Now [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) operation will be able to provide first 2KB from the file. But but there is no way to [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) last 1KB even if the application place File position after 3KB.

If above assumptions are correct
[Please note that some intruder messing with the file is not considered here ]

- Application does NOT need to place it's own checksum when writing to a file and verify it when reading back (even after a abrupt OS shutdown)
- Application can assume provided data from [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) is what it wrote originally and worst thing that can happen is NOT being able to read data from end of the file

**Is these assumptions wrong (in OS=Linux RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.X and File system=EXT4,XFS  context) ? If so kindly please let me know which of them are wrong**.

Comment: I don't think ext4 protects against bitrot like that.

Comment: can be done at a lower (block) layer: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-integrity.html (which can be combined together with dm-crypt too, including with LUKS).

Comment: Use BTRFS as filesystem, as it natively provides checksums for all files.

Answer (score 0):

> File systems like EXT4 and XFS. Writes blocks to disk (Could be a Hard Disk or a SSD) along with a checksum.

No, neither file system has data checksums.

> When Reading back, if checksum fails, read operation will NOT return data and will indicate error or EOF (or no data).

No. As said, no data checksumming is done, but even if it *were*, there would be no `EOF` (that would be wrong!) but an error code `EIO` would be set.

> On a re-boot (even if it is after a abrupt shutdown where OS in-memory pages were not flushed), Linux OS checks the integrity of file blocks using checksum.

No. These are journaling file systems and hence, whole-filesystem checksum checks are usually not necessary. Also, as said, there's no data checksums in either file system (there's checksums for the file metadata, at least in XFS)

Also, no, even for the checksums that exist, and even for the file systems that have data checksums, Linux as operating system will not do a whole-volume check. That would take ages, and is something that can very well be left to user land software. It would also, considering the fact that a broken checksum probably means the storage device is beginning to fail, do more harm than good. As said, complete file system checks are very rarely done on modern file systems. Instead, checks on access are common.

> and if an application tries to read a file where such error detected blocks are part of it, read operation will fail when the read reaches the afore mentioned block.

no, because no data checksums are present. But let's assume they were:

> If the corruption detected(by Linux OS) block is in the middle of a file. Even if subsequent blocks does NOT contain an error, read operation will fail after reaching the corrupted block and application will never be able to read beyond the corrupted block.

No. I don't think Linux nor POSIX make any guarantees on that, and no reasonable file system driver for a file system with data checksums would read 1GB of data to check checksums when you `seek` to the position after that 1GB. So, your assumption is wrong.

> e.g. Let's say file size is 4KB, and block size 1KB. So this file will be spread across 4 blocks A,B,C and D.

Not in detail how XFS works, and usually also not how ext4 works. You might want to look up what extent-based allocation is.

> Let's say Linux detected that block C is corrupted.

Again, even if either file system *had* data checksums, that would only happen the moment C is read. Not earlier.

> Now read operation will be able to provide first 2KB from the file.

Why shouldn't you be able to `fseek` beyond that?

> But but there is no way to read last 1KB even if the application place File position after 3KB.

As explained above, that's wrong.

However,

> Application does NOT need to place it's own checksum when writing to a file and verify it when reading back (even after a abrupt OS shutdown)

Yes, placing data integrity in the hands of the application instead of the hands of the block device abstraction would be a *bad* design mistake.

The whole point of a file system is that applications do not need to be aware of the physical medium they store data on. Keeping that abstraction free from leaking the ugly details of the underlying hardware means that the applications cannot be aware of the error probabilities, the kind of errors that can occur, and their position on the physical medium.

All this, however, would be necessary to make a sensible choice on redundancy information.

In short: **When using a file system to store data on a block device, it's the block device layer that guarantees data integrity, not the application layer**.

> Application can assume provided data from read is what it wrote originally and worst thing that can happen is NOT being able to read data from end of the file

Applications *Must* assume data read from files is correct, otherwise it also couldn't assume the application is correct, or anything else they do is correct. Again, that's a guarantee that the file system offers to the application. You're using a file system, so you assume that.

> Is these assumptions wrong (in OS=Linux RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.X and File system=EXT4,XFS context) ? If so kindly please let me know which of them are wrong.

As seen above, basically all your assumptions were wrong :(

Comment: _"Yes, placing data integrity in the hands of the application instead of the hands of the block device abstraction would be a bad design mistake."_ -- I'm not sure all database engineers would agree here. And this, _"Applications Must assume data read from files is correct"_, is just wrong enough to be dangerous. Isn't the usual recommendation to validate all inputs, since you never know where a file came from, or if it was created by a broken or outright malicious system? And for a reason, since a lot of the data we process comes from someone else we've never met.

Comment: Unrelated to the bigger issues, even with extent-based allocation, if the storage is divided into numbered blocks, a 4 kB file will still need four 1 kB blocks. Whether the bookkeeping says it's 4 blocks starting at block 123, or if it says it's the 4 blocks 123, 124, 125, 126, it doesn't really change the basic idea.

Comment: @ilkkachu hi :) easier things to address first: Re: extents/blocks: yeah, that's why I chose the wording "not in detail how… works". I hoped that would make things clearer; seemingly didn't. (and the thing is that the existing checksums refer to metadata, and that describes extents)

Comment: @ilkkachu re: Database engineers: Heh, that's a good point you're making there. But I'm not sure it's really in conflict with what I say, in practice. What databases typically do (disclaimer: no idea about anything but small-scale InnoDB(Mysql), Postgres and SQLite) is having mechanisms for recovery when the system fails *as specified*, especially mechanisms recovering from a system breakdown with unfinished data writes. The assumption is still that what is read from storage was what was written, only that it's uncertain whether a write completed. Now, I bet you're 100% on point and especially

Comment: … large databases beyond terabytes with high throughputs do well having their own data optionally contain checksums, for data integrity instead of just checking whether an operation completed successfully. "Perfect storage" is a bad approximation once you have enough billons of bits that can flip with a nonzero probability. Still, the usual ways (and which we see in servers) is that a) RAM being a likely culprit here, we integrate forward error correction into that hardware (ECC) and b) storage being a likely culprit here, we integrate error correction into that:

Comment: Consumer hard drives and SSDs, just like the different flavors of use case optimized server storage, make extensive use of error-correction on the hardware level. As a matter of fact, modern storage would not at all be possible without modern error correction coding. The price differences between, for example, a read-perf optimized server SAS SSD and a pro/consumer SATA SSD is, aside from the interface, that the vendor will use more of the physical memory for error correction information, and preselect flash elements that promise to have lower error rates. Then, atop of that, comes a layer (

Comment: (or three) of redundancy in terms of RAID architectures, integrity layers, and distributed replicas, and only then comes the file system (if any) and the database. So, I'm fairly positive that while I can understand the potential need for databases to verify integrity, I'd see that need as something met by the lower layers. A checksum, like any other mechanism, never gives 100% certainty, but it can state something like "Under the assumption of {model of what kind of errors occur}, with a probability of 1-2·10⁻¹², if the checksum matches the data, the data is correct". Move that down the stack

Comment: into the layers that actually still have a chance to correct the error instead of just detecting it, and you achieve two things: 1) the database (or generally application) developers don't have to assume that their storage might not be giving what they wrote some time ago, greatly simplifying things 2) you leave the mechanisms for correction of errors up to the instance where there's actual knowledge on the failure behaviour of the underlying storage. (That's essentially why things like Ceph are so popular once you're large enough to afford that many disks: Applications don't need to care

Comment: … that you currently have to pull a case of 32 hard drives from the server, replace four of them and plug it back in; the abstraction "storage with an error rate < 10⁻¹⁴" holds. Imagine you'd have to configure your database in accordance to knowing a precise model of how likely bit errors in your storage are, and how many errors per year you can afford to make… that'd be annoying, and asking the wrong people to compensate hardware imperfections)

Comment: **Mind you, Databases are already the special case** where one could argue, knowledge on storage characterists *is* in scope for the application. For something that just reads files, I'd argue, you never even *want* someone to have to think about that. How should my, say, Libreoffice know whether I'm saving that document for transferal using a 2004 giveaway free USB thumb drive, or whether it lands directly on a shared drive in my company's datacenter-grade storage cluster? It can't, and it shouldn't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for responding. I am NOT worried about some intruder modifying the files here(added this to question).  So as per your answer I guess application can expect what it written to be read completely/partially/empty BUT not incorrectly. Am I correct ?   Also,  as per your answer, it is possible that read call to NOT to be able to read from middle of the file, but be able to read from beginning and end of the same file ? If that is so, does file size consider only valid(detected by block device) blocks ?

Comment: I never assumed you were concerned about intruders, @aKumara. No, you cannot assume that, because, again, there's no data checksums, so read data *might* be incorrect. But it might also be incorrect even with checksum, just with a lower probability. File size had nothing to do with correct or incorrect data, it's quite obvious you still think there's some magic way that files are checked as complete unit. That's never the case. It's one of the main points of my answer!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for taking your time. Sorry, I am confused bit now. As per your answer Block device performs integrity check. So I assumed, when Linux read call is issued for the particular region of the file, when eventually that request reach the Block device, it performs the integrity check. And if the integrity check fails, read call should fail. Could you kindly pls clarify.

Comment: No, my answer does not say that. Muggy answer says that if you do integrity checks, you *should* do it on the block device abstraction level.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, so is below what you are saying ?                                1. Neither Linux nor XFS/EXT4(except for meta data checksum) does checksum validation.     2. Application level checksum validation is a bad design.     3. Block device should do the validation.     But if I have no control over the used Block device(i.e. has to cater different types - e.g. SSD, HDD) AND I am restricted to use only XFS and EXT4 (and Linux 8.X)  THEN only option I have is to do Application level checksum validation ?

Comment: 1. they don't do *data checksum validation* is because they don't **have data checksums**. (not doing validation and not having checksums is two different things) 2. yes 3. no.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, could you pls clarify on "3. no".  Did you mean my re-cap of your 
 statement "Block device should do the validation" is incorrect and you meant something else ?  Also is "If I have no control over the used Block device(i.e. has to cater different types - e.g. SSD, HDD) AND I am restricted to use only XFS and EXT4 (and Linux 8.X) THEN only option I have is to do Application level checksum validation ?" correct then ?

Comment: Yes, I meant your recap is incorrect. And no, application level is not your only choice. See the comments above.